# Rails Server Route Error When Accessing Via IP Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new here and working on a Rails application that was handed to me for a research project.

I have created my own instance of the project and I am able to access the server running the instance from my computer, BUT, only if I modify my hosts file and map the IP address to an arbitrary domain name.

If I try to access the rails server via an IP address, I get the following error:

"Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes."

So my question is, how would I configure the Rails server and application to be accessible via IP address only, for example: http://52.78.233.65:3000/, and why would the server work if I modify the hosts file but not visit the site directly?

Comment: Why don't you develop locally?

Comment: Generally that is how I have started but I needed to get feedback on some changes and wished to send the link out to my peers for feedback.

Comment: There are two industry standards to achieve this: 1. Use VCS, such as `git`. 2. If the peers can't deploy the app locally, use staging environment, e.g. on Heroku (it is free for small amount of users).

Answer (score 0):

If you need remote access, you can choose one of below methods:

- Apply in each start

  - Start rails server by appending -b 0.0.0.0, so command to start rails server is: **rails s -b 52.78.233.65** (from your sample IP)
- Change default binding option

  - Modify config/boot.rb by adding below code and start rails server with normal command rails s

config/boot.rb

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails  
  class Server
    alias :default_options_bk :default_options
    def default_options
      default_options_bk.merge!(Host: '0.0.0.0')
    end
  end
end
```